# How to select multiple elements from multiple vectors in a list

Tags: r, list, indexing, subset

Is there a way to select multiple elements of multiple vectors stored in a list? The position of each element I am interested in selecting for each vector is the same. Consider the following MWE of a list with a length of 3. Each vector within the list is of equal length too.

```
# create list and vectors within storing random data
mylist<- list(rnorm(5), rgeom(5, 0.05), rbinom(5, 10, 0.5))
```

If I want to select the 1st and 3rd element of the 1st vector I write `mylist[[1]][c(1,3)]` and this returns the values of elements in position 1 and 3. Similarly, for the second vector, I write `mylist[[2]][c(1,3)]`.

But how can I write some neat code so that I can select the 1st and 3rd element of both the 1st and 2nd vectors in the list at the same time? I have tried `mylist[c(1, 2)][c(1, 3)]` but this returns all the elements of the 1st vector and `NULL` for the second vector.

**EDIT**

Once the elements have been selected how does one overwrite them, such that (for example) `mylist[c(1, 2)][c(1,3)] <- 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `lapply`

```
lapply(mylist[1:2], `[`, c(1, 3))

#[[1]]
#[1] -0.5604756  1.5587083

#[[2]]
#[1]  6 55
```

which is similar to `map` in `purrr`

```
purrr::map(mylist[1:2], `[`, c(1, 3))
```

---

To update the values of selected elements, we can do

```
mylist[1:2] <-lapply(mylist[1:2], function(x) {x[c(1, 3)] <- 0;x})
mylist
#[[1]]
#[1]  0.00000000 -0.23017749  0.00000000  0.07050839  0.12928774

#[[2]]
#[1]  0 61  0  8  8

#[[3]]
#[1] 4 3 8 7 6
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
mylist<- list(rnorm(5), rgeom(5, 0.05), rbinom(5, 10, 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks, @RonakShah. Your answer is very helpful. However, I omitted a step thinking I would be able to integrate the answer to achieve my desired result. Please, see the edit I included. Perhaps you could expand on your answer considering the changes?

Comment: @altfi_SU okay. I just updated the answer to integrate the changes.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map_at`

```
library(purrr)
map_at(mylist, 1:2, ~ replace(.x, c(1, 3), 0))
#[[1]]
#[1]  0.00000000 -0.23017749  0.00000000  0.07050839  0.12928774

#[[2]]
#[1]  0 61  0  8  8

#[[3]]
#[1] 4 3 8 7 6
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
mylist<- list(rnorm(5), rgeom(5, 0.05), rbinom(5, 10, 0.5)
```